# prove that is big-Oh

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Show that $2\sqrt n + n^{1/3} \log_2(n) = O(\sqrt n)$. I need help understanding how to solve this limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2\sqrt n + n^{1/3} \log_2(n)}{\sqrt n}$$

thanks

Comment: Just note that $\log n$ grows slower than any power of $n$, in particular slower than $n^{1/6}$. Thus, there is a $C>0$ such that $$
2\sqrt n  + n^{1/3} \log n \le 2\sqrt n  + n^{1/3} (Cn^{1/6}  )= (2 + C)\sqrt n .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $2+\dfrac{\log_2 e\cdot \ln n}{n^{\frac{1}{6}}}$. Observe that the second term tends to $0$ as the $n^{\frac{1}{6}}$ dominates the $\ln n$, hence the limit is a non-zero constant ( $2$ in this case ).